# Convert database record to readable text - ASP

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access

Is it possible to do that? I mean, let's supose I have a database with the following records:

```
J
M
A
```

And when reading to put all the values on an HTML table, I want them to show as:

```
John
Michael
Anna
```

How can I do that instead of doing "if A then Anna else if J then John" etc...

Comment: Why would the data in the database be just "J" and not "John"? The information needs to be somewhere and database is the right place for this. What if there is also ***Jim*** or ***Matt** would you still store just "J" or "M"? How to distinguish it from ***John*** and ***Michael***?

Comment: This was an example data.

Comment: I have a table which store values - "400". And I need to be stored as values. But when read on the html, I need it to show "England". And "500" for "Spain", etc..

Comment: @FilipePires See my answer. Normally, you would create a separate table that maps the keys ("400", "500",...) with the values ("England", "Spain",...). Keys like "400" are the primary key of that table and they are used as foreign key in another table. However, it seems that you are looking to hard code this. That can be done using a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie and is it possible to do that in a simple .mdb (Access) db?

Comment: That's a different question than the original one, but yes: it's one of the basic principles of relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a field that consists of a single character indicating a specific name. In your code, you want to convert that single character to the full name.

You can use a `Dictionary` to do this:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["A"] = "Anna";
dict["J"] = "John";
dict["M"] = "Michael";
```

Now when you have the single character, you can get the name like this:

```
string name = dict["A"];
```

If by any chance you're using VB, then you can create such an array like this:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
dict.Add("A", "Anna")
dict.Add("J", "John")
dict.Add("M", "Michael")
```

Now you can get the name like this:

```
dict.Item("A");
```

See for instance [VB.NET Dictionary Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet)

Note: usually, people don't hard code such an array. In a relational database, there's usually an extra table that maps that character to the name. Using SQL, you can then make sure that the query returns the name instead of the character.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Lowagie . In fact, I need to hard code this...
It is a great idea... But it isn't working as expected:
"Script error detected at line 7. 
Source line: IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(); 
Description: Sintax error"

Comment: My answer is in C#. Which language are you using? (Your question received downvotes because its quality is very low: you should improve your question, among others by explaining if you're using C#, VB,...)

Comment: @FilipePires I've added the VB version of the code.

Comment: But asp.net is a technology, not a language, is it?

Comment: See the [asp.net tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info), where there are references to [asp.net in VB](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1430243295/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) and [asp.net in C#](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1118311809/?tag=stackoverfl08-20). The more robust applications are written in C#, and that's why I gave the C# example first. I still don't know what you're using though.